# Laravel 5: Controller not found in /Http/Controllers despite it being there

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get this error when accessing the route calling a method from LoginController:

```
 ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\LoginController does not exist
```

The problem is that the file "LoginController.php" IS there in the directory "App\Http\Controllers" but laravel refuses to see it. I'm stumped!

My controller file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAuthentication(Request $request) {
      // method code here
    }
}
```

My routes file:

```
<?php
    Route::get('/', function() {
            session('userLevelKey', '1');
            return view('layout');
    });

    Route::post('/', 'LoginController@loginAuthentication');
    // some more routes
```

edit 1: added namepace to controller file.

Comment: Can you add the namespace of your LoginController to the question.

Comment: If ther is no namespace add it `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` :)

Comment: I'll add that now.
edit: The same error still appears :/

Answer (score 4):

change your controller file to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAuthentication(Request $request) {
      // method code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the same error appears.

Comment: if you are using 'post ' method dont forget to pass csrf token, and if you are not using csrf token , comment it from 'Kernel.php' ....  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: also check if 'rewrite mode' is on,and if 'allow override all' is set in  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf . And also clear cache using commands 'composer dump-autoload', 
'php artisan cache:clear' ,
'php artisan config:clear'

Answer (score 0):

add path to controlles to route page App\Http\Controllers